# NVENCを使用したh.264エンコードにおけるビットレートの実質上限を突破できないか

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-10

Windows 10（64bit）にてffmpegを使用し、H.264によるMPEG4エンコードを行っています。
通常のCPUによるエンコードではエンコード速度に限界があるため、NVENCによるハードウェアエンコードをトライしているのですが、ビットレートを指定してもある一定のビットレート以上の書き出しができず、困っています。

具体的には

ffmpeg -i （元ファイル） -vcodec nvenc_h264 -vf stereo3d=sbsl:abl -b:v 60M -s 2160x2160 -r 60 -c:a copy （書き出し先ファイル）

といった形で60MbpsのMP4ファイルを生成しようとしても、実測で35Mbps付近までしかビットレートが上がりません。
NVENCを使用しなければ60Mbpsで書き出しができるので、素人考えで「エンコーダーの仕様なのかな？」と考えているのですが、CPUに比べてNVENCで変換すると実行速度が1/5まで早くなるため、なんとか60Mbpsで書き出しができないものかと悩んでおります。

まだffmpegを始めたばかりでミスなどもあるかもしれません。忌憚なくご指摘いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

追記：タイトルの編集を頂きありがとうございます。
変換元のファイルについて補足説明いたします。元ファイルは3840x960のMP4（60MBps、60フレーム、h.264 / AVCコーデック）で、side by sideの3D視聴用の動画データです。これを「同じコーデック・ビットレート・フレーム数」でTop to bottom（2160x2160）形式に変換しようとしています。併せてご参考にしていただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 逆質問で申し訳ないのですが「35Mbpsではまだ映像品質的に満足できない」のでしょうか？MP4形式+H.264コーデック圧縮では、ビットレートをそろえるための詰め物データ（＝ゴミ）を出力しないため、本質的に必要な情報しか格納されません。

Comment: ご質問ありがとうございます。簡単に申し上げますと、データを渡す先方から「60Mbps程度で」と指定されているため、60Mbpsで出力しています。
現状ではCPUを使うことで60Mbps付近での書き出しができているのでNVENCを使わずにエンコードを行っているのですが、NVENCを使用した場合の処理速度が劇的に早くなるため、NVENCを活用できる方法がないかと探しております。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 動作環境は手元にないのですが[ffmpegソース](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/nvenc.c)を眺めた感じだと、`qmin`, `qmax`指定が効くかもしれません。極端ですが`qmin`=1, `qmax`=10などを設定すると高レート出力になりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。早速試してみます。お時間を頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 試したところ、高レート出力を行うことができました。誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。ありがとうございました。
以下のコマンドにより、60Mbps付近で変換を行うことができました。

```
ffmpeg -i （元ファイル名） -vcodec nvenc_h264 -vf stereo3d=sbsl:abl -b:v 60M -minrate 60M -maxrate 60M -qmin 1 -qmax 20 -s 2160x2160 -r 60 -c:a copy （書き出し先ファイル名）
```

@yohjp さん、非常に参考になりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 目的は達せられたようで何よりです。簡単に補足しておくと: H.264エンコーダのQP値（画品質と圧縮率の調整パラメータ）を、値域`qmin`～`qmax`間に強制的に制限します。QP値が小さいほど、きれいな映像／高いビットレートになります。一般的にはエンドユーザがQP値を指定するのではなく、目標ビットレートだけを指定すればよいはずなのですが、今回はNVENCレート制御のアルゴリズム特性もあるのか、明示的にQP値の幅を制限すると期待通り動作したようですね。（異なるビットレート帯の出力が欲しければ、別の`qmin`,`qmax`に調整することになります。）

Comment: @yohjp さん、解説頂きありがとうございます。
ご教示頂いたことで、QP値のディフォルト値などを学ぶきっかけとなりました。
参考のためにご報告しますと、qmaxの値を10にしたところ80Mbps近くまでビットレートが上がることがわかりました（当方のマシンはnVIDIA GT 740を搭載しています）。そこでqmaxの値を調整した結果、20で元データと同様のビットレートになった次第です。
またご質問させて頂く事かと思いますが、今後とも皆様何卒よろしくお願いいたします。